# Спарсить данные из json в таблицу на js

Tags: javascript, json

Хей, гайс. Может быть ещё кто-нибудь столь поздней ночью сможет обратить свой взор на мою проблему. Дело вот в чём: необходимо в таблицу хтмл, созданную в js занести данные. Пробую один способ, прикрепляю листинг программы. Нужно чтобы данные парсились из json и заполняли таблицу в виде(id,name,price,quantity - имена столбцов):

```js
function createTable(parent, rows, cols) {
  var table = document.createElement('table');
  var MyJson = [{
      "id": "123",
      "name": "iPhone XS",
      "price": "1600",
      "quantity": "10"
    },
    {
      "id": "344",
      "name": "Samsung Galaxy S7",
      "price": "550",
      "quantity": "7"
    },
    {
      "id": "266",
      "name": "Macbook",
      "price": "900",
      "quantity": "7"
    },
    {
      "id": "478",
      "name": "Asus",
      "price": "400",
      "quantity": "8"
    },
    {
      "id": "569",
      "name": "Acer",
      "price": "300",
      "quantity": "4"
    },
    {
      "id": "788",
      "name": "TP-LINK",
      "price": "100",
      "quantity": "10"
    },
    {
      "id": "124",
      "name": "iPhone SE",
      "price": "350",
      "quantity": "11"
    },
    {
      "id": "345",
      "name": "Samsung Galaxy Note Boom",
      "price": "690",
      "quantity": "8"
    },
    {
      "id": "267",
      "name": "Surface Boom",
      "price": "690",
      "quantity": "8"
    }
  ];

  //добавление thead'а 
  var tr1 = document.createElement('tr');
  //заполнение строки tr ячейками th 
  for (var k = 0; k < cols; k++) {
    var th = document.createElement('th');
    tr1.appendChild(th);
  }
  table.appendChild(tr1);
  //добавление tbody 
  var Myobj = JSON.parse(MyJson);
  for (var i = 0; i < rows - 1; i++) {
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
      var td = document.createElement('td');
      if (j === 0) td.innerHTML = Myobj[i].id;
      else if (j === 1) td.innerHTML = Myobj[i].name;
      else if (j === 2) td.innerHTML = Myobj[i].price;
      else td.innerHTML = Myobj[i].quantity;
      tr.appendChild(td); //добавить td в tr 
    }
    table.appendChild(tr); //добавить tr в table 
  }
  //добавление всего table 
  parent.appendChild(table);
}
```

Чуть поясню код(это необходимо): в хтмл доке есть кнопка, нажав на которую должна появиться табл на 4 столбца с заголовками id, name, price , quantity.
для этого в хтмл-ке вызываю метод createTable, у которого на входе ссылка на родительский DOM-элемент таблицы, кол-во строк и кол-во столбцов. в функции создаю таблицу через createElement tr,td и т.д. В итоге при нажатии на кнопку в хтмл доке, как будто никакой скрипт не выполняется(табл просто напросто не видна). Хтмл док:

```html
<div class="buttons">
  <button class="but1" onclick="createTable(elem,11,4)">
          <span class="first">Name,price</span>
        </button>
</div>
<div id="elem">
  <!--сюда вставляем таблицу -->
</div>
<script>
  var elem = document.querySelector('#elem');
</script>
</body>
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

Подскажите, чё здесь не так

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот в этом раз:

```
var MyJson = 
[ 
  { "id":"12
```

Вот в этом два:

```
var Myobj = JSON.parse(MyJson);
```

У вас первое - **объект**, второе - преобразование **строки** к объекту

или MyJson должен быть строкой, или не нужно делать преобразования.

```
var MyJson = 
'[ '+
  '{ "id":"123","name":"iPhone XS","price": "1600","quantity":"10"}, '+
  '{ "id":"344","name":"Samsung Galaxy S7","price": "550","quantity":"7"}, '+
  '{ "id":"266","name":"Macbook","price": "900","quantity":"7"},'+ 
  '{ "id":"478","name":"Asus","price": "400","quantity":"8"}, '+
  '{ "id":"569","name":"Acer","price": "300","quantity":"4"}, '+
  '{ "id":"788","name":"TP-LINK","price": "100","quantity":"10"}, '+
  '{ "id":"124","name":"iPhone SE","price": "350","quantity":"11"}, '+
  '{ "id":"345","name":"Samsung Galaxy Note Boom","price": "690","quantity":"8"}, '+
  '{ "id":"267","name":"Surface Boom","price": "690","quantity":"8"}'+ 
']';
```

Comment: Владимир, а как MyJson сделать строкой? ( я просто новичок в js)

Comment: @ОкуневПаша Например в кавычки заключить, в одинарные, все строки

Comment: Владимир, вроде в точности скопировал ваш код, но табл всё равно не появляется. Может ещё какие-то прорехи в коде есть?

Comment: https://yadi.sk/i/cRpAYn8AbexzHQ
https://yadi.sk/i/DfuD6ZAjOHurrA
https://yadi.sk/i/Ezk7fkxwzn6CoA
Код скопирован ваш, за исключением этого изменения

Comment: Владимир, это вы в js файле писали, а мне по условию надо вызывать createElement при нажатии на кнопку в хтмл файле. Я попробовал написать <button class="but1" onclick="createTable(document.querySelector('#elem'),11,4)">, но безрезультатно, как мне правильно вызвать createTable из хтмл?

Comment: @ОкуневПаша https://yadi.sk/i/96g8KecnDAMScg

Comment: Владимир, всё заработало! Переписал всё в точности как у вас и вуаля! Благодарствую

Comment: @ОкуневПаша не нужно писать подобных комментариев, если вас устроил ответ - поставте галочку, если вам он просто понравился но он вам не подходит - проголосуйте за него.